# PowerShell - Console Input using Explorer

Tags: powershell

Scenario:  User is trying to upload a document from a PowerShell 3.0 script.

Current mechanism:  Read-Host.  Simple string prompt to request path/file.ext.

Desired behavior:  A prompt ('Please choose the file to upload') and 
Explorer is launched.  The path/file the user selects is passed along to my script.

I can see how to launch Explorer of course, just can't figure how to tie the command line 
prompt and the file selection with Explorer together.

Kind Regards,

Paul

Comment: google "file dialog powershell" first result: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/09/01/hey-scripting-guy-september-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple script to do what you're wanting to do. Also you can use PowerGUI To compile the script and have the Powershell Window close Automatically close the powershell window after it's finished, but that's not needed.

```
$DestinationFolder = "L:\Users\caleb.berger\Desktop";

function Get-FileName($initialDirectory) {  
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") |     Out-Null

$OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog;
$OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory;
$OpenFileDialog.filter = "All files (*.*)| *.*";
$OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null;
$OpenFileDialog.filename;
}

Write-Host "Please Select The File To Upload:";
$SourceFile = Get-FileName -initialDirectory "c:\";

Write-Host "Copying File...";
Copy-Item -LiteralPath $SourceFile -Destination $DestinationFolder -Force;
Write-Host "Finished.";
Read-Host "Press Any Key To Continue";
```

You can learn more about how this works at:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/09/01/hey-scripting-guy-september-1.aspx

His script is what I built this application off of.

Comment: while i welcome your answer we shouldnt really be encouraging such poorly researched questions by answering them imho

Comment: Fair warning: `LoadWithPartialName()` is [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12xc5368(v=vs.110).aspx) and has been since at least .NET 2.0.  You're supposed to use `Load()` instead.